# ActiveMQ recovered message exception:GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, activemq-classic

all.

I'am get this error with testing activeMQ.

I send about 200,000 message into MQ,per message about 8k.

then I stop MQ server,then start it,but is not work well.

exec: ./activemq console

I found this message:

> INFO | cursor for queue://test.mqtest has recovered 140000 messages.
>   67% complete  INFO | cursor for queue://test.mqtest has recovered
>   150000 messages. 72% complete  INFO | cursor for queue://test.mqtest
>   has recovered 160000 messages. 77% complete  INFO | cursor for
>   queue://test.mqtest has recovered 170000 messages. 82% complete  INFO
>   | Compacted the leveldb index at: /ssd/mq_producer/dirty.index in 1.84
>   ms  INFO | cursor for queue://test.mqtest has recovered 180000
>   messages. 87% complete  INFO | No IOExceptionHandler registered,
>   ignoring IO exception java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient.might_fail(LevelDBClient.scala:543)

I got the exception is about jvm GC.But I don't know how it happened with activeMQ?

and configuration of a relationship?

Comment: your java process needs more memory.

Comment: I would try giving it more memory.  What is you maximum heap size. i.e. your `-Xmx` option?

Comment: To avoid further complications, make sure to commit your messages once you received them